# How to write mutilple lines in a text file by calling same method different time?

Tags: java

I come up with a problem.

This is my method below:

```
public void someMethod()
{
    StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();
    String edited = "My String Line";
    newFile.append(edited);
    newFile.append("\n");
    FileWriter fstreamWrite = new FileWriter("transaction.txt");
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstreamWrite);
    out.write(newFile.toString());
    out.close();
}
```

And when I am calling this method in my main class more than one time so this code is creating my transaction.txt with a line "My String Line". But when I am to call this method more than one time to  write the "My String Line" several time, it just overriding the line and not giving me the output like.

My String Line

My String Line

My String Line

When I call the method 3 times.

Any idea how to write the same line multiple times as by calling the same method multiple times?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you want to append to a file . Then you can use the constructor [FileWriter(java.io.File,boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,boolean)):

> **Parameters:**
>
> file - a File object to write to
>
> append - if true, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning

Hence change the code to :

```
new FileWriter("transaction.txt",true);
```

---

To write a new line to the file , use [BufferedWriter#newLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29).

> Writes a line separator. The line separator string is defined by the system property line.separator, and is not necessarily a single newline ('\n') character.

Comment: yes it works but it writing in the same line like My String LineMy String LineMy String Line.......... any idea how to write separate line

Comment: That being said, it is questionable uf it is a good idea to open a file every time you want to append a line.

Comment: yes it works but it writing in the same line like My String LineMy String LineMy String Line.......... any idea how to write separate line

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad idea to open a file just to write a few lines there. A better approach is to pass the Writer to your method as argument:

```
public void someMethod(BufferedWriter writer) throws IOExcpetion {
    // setup your data to write
    StringBuilder sb = .....
    // actually write it
    writer.write(sb.toString());
    writer.newLine()
}
```

Once you have this, you can use it in a setting like this:

```
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
    bw = .... // open the writer
    while (...) {
       someMethod(bw);
    }
    bw.close();
} catch (IOException io) {
    // handle IOException here
} 
...
finally {
    // make sure bw is closed
}
```